# How to update a sql table column with a new value computed by SQL function?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table TABLE with cols A and B and following values

```
A  B
1  0
1  0
2  0
2  0
3  0
4  0
```

I want to update the column B with the function `theFunc(A)` taking col A as an argument. There are many rows, therefore it takes very long time if I use the query like

UPDATE TABLE 
SET B = theFunc(A)

I believe if I compute all the values for each unique col A value then map these to related rows , it will be faster instead of computation for each row. How can I do that in SQL?

Comment: just make it in a temporary table then update the other table with the temp table

Answer (score 0):

```
update tab t1 set t1.B = (select t2.C from (select theFunc(A) C from tab group by A) t2 where t2.C = t1.A);
```